# How to set a gitlab CI token in runner with rights to write to repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to tag a build and when trying to push the tags I get the below error in CI

How to create a CI token and set in the build environment which can push tags to the repository.

```
[01:59:14]: Exit status of command 'git push origin --tags' was 128 instead of 0.
remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gxx.yy.zz.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: what runner type you use?

Comment: If you mean the runner executable type, I'm using the shell runner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two options you can do:

1. Use a [personal access token](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens) with `write_repository` permissions.

   - Save it as a [custom CI/CD Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#create-a-custom-variable-in-the-ui) and ensure it is `masked`.
   - Use the custom CI/CD variable in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

   ```
   script:
     - git remote add https-origin https://gitlab-ci-token:${YOUR_PERSONAL_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/group/sub-group/project.git
     - git tag <some tag>
     - git push https-origin -o ci.skip refs/tags/<some tag>
   ```

Note the `-o ci.skip` to not start a new pipeline, however this depends on your scenario.

This option is definitely better if you create a bot account, so you can better control which repositories the bot account has access to, as otherwise, any maintainer or above can easily retrieve that `write_repository` key from looking in the settings.

---

2. If you have access to the specific runner which the build is running on via `tags`, you can use a [Deploy Keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/) which saves you on using a bot account or your own personal access token.

   - This requires an SSH-key to be created on the gitlab-runner machine, and copying it to the repositories `Settings -> Repository -> Deploy Keys` and pasting the public key within there (and also ticking `Write access allowed`).
   - You should then be able to use your standard `git push origin --tags` command as before.

---

GitLab are looking to improve the permission problem in the Epic:

- [Make pipeline permissions more controllable and flexible](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/3559)

The specific issue for `write_repository` using the pipeline token being:

- [Allow `write_repository` scope for pipeline permissions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223679).

Answer (score 2):

As Rekovni says,first,you should create personal access token,I use `*********************` to refer your personal access token.Then go to `setting -> CI/CD -> Variables`, add `*********************` into Variables,set key name to `YOUR_PERSONAL_TOKEN`.

| Type | Key | Value | Protected | Masked | Environments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Variable | YOUR_PERSONAL_TOKEN | ********************* | × | √ | All (default) |

set git remote url in script like this:

```yaml
  script:
    - CI_PUSH_REPO=`echo "$CI_REPOSITORY_URL" | sed 's/^.*@/@/g'`
    - git remote set-url --push origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:${YOUR_PERSONAL_TOKEN}$CI_PUSH_REPO"
#   - git push xxx
```

It works for me